# VSCode doesn't breakpoint properly within .vue files

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, debugging

When I use VSCode and debug a test of a Vue component, my breakpoints inside that component 'hit' but are essentially useless to me.

Either:

- I can't inspect variables
- It breakpoints in the wrong place, lines away from where I set the debugger
- It doesn't breakpoint at all

See this image for an example. See how the breakpoint icon is midway between `va` and `lue` ?
If I hover over any of those variables, it acts like I'm not even debugging.

If I use the debug console to view the `input` variable, it tells me it's not defined.

Anyone know how to get this to work nicely?

I've got various extensions installed such as:

- JS + Typescript
- Jest
- Volar

[image: Problem]

[image]

Comment: If you debug minified code then `input` isn't a correct name for a var

Comment: @EstusFlask I'm just debugging Jest tests so no minification should be happening